# C++ code works in GDB online but not in Code:Blocks

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I can't figure out why my program works in GDB online but doesn't work in Code:Blocks. It is supposed to allow one to input their hourly rate, then input how many hours they have worked over the last 4 weeks, add these totals together and return the total to the user. It is supposed to use a function that takes the hours as an argument. In Code:Blocks it terminates the program after the first amount of hours is entered. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// function declaration
float getGross(float hs[], int n);

int main()
{

  float hours[4], sum;
  sum = getGross(hours, 4);
  cout << "Gross pay: $ " << setprecision(2) << fixed << sum << endl;
  return 0;

}

// function definition
float getGross(float hs[], int n)
{
  float wage, ot, total;

  cout << "Please enter your hourly wage: " << endl;
  cin >> wage;

  cout << "Enter hours worked in each of the past four weeks (hit enter after each entry): " << endl;
  //  Storing 4 number entered by user in an array

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
      //  Holding the array of hours entered
     cin >> hs[i];

      int j;
      float weekPay[4];

      if(hs[i] > 40)
      {
          ot = (hs[i] - 40) * 1.5;
          weekPay[j] = (wage * 40) + (ot * wage);
          total += weekPay[j];
      }
      else
      {
          weekPay[j] = (wage * hs[i]);
          total += weekPay[j];
      }
  }

  return total;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: So when you stepped through it in a debugger, what did you learn?

Comment: `j` is uninitialized.

Comment: In Code:Blocks it terminates the program after the first amount of hours is entered.

Comment: I just use GDB to compile and run my code because the Code:Blocks I have to use for school is in a virtual envrionment and is very slow

Comment: Once I get things working in GDB I go enter the code in Code:Blocks.

Comment: I thought it is initialized inside the for loop?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. It's the first thing you should learn how to do, right after you've got your first hello world program running.

Comment: @crawfbigg No it is not and neither is `total`. Use: `float total = 0;`. I don't see why you even need `j` or `weekPay`. Just do `total += (wage * 40) + (ot * wage);` and `total += (wage * hs[i]);`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, thank you a ton, I will try this on my lunch break currently at work. I see now what everyone means, I declared it, I did not initialize it. But as you said I shouldn't even need it.

Comment: @crawfbigg -- And before you ask, the issue is that C++ has something called *undefined behavior*.  That's why it "works" on one compiler and crashes when run using another compiler.  You make mistakes like this, then your program will run in an unpredictable state.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks Paul. And thanks to everyone that chimed in. I will keep plugging away to get better at coding. Coding is the first subject I have ever ran into that kick my arse like it has. Respect to all that have earned their stripes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `int j`, at line 40 is not initalized and that causes a runtime error.

Tried to clean up the code:

```
// function definition
float getGross(float hs[], int n)
{
    float wage, ot, total = 0;

    cout << "Please enter your hourly wage: " << endl;
    cin >> wage;

    cout << "Enter hours worked in each of the past four weeks (hit enter after each entry): " << endl;
    //  Storing 4 number entered by user in an array

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
       //  Holding the array of hours entered
       cin >> hs[i];

       if (hs[i] > 40)
       {
           ot = (hs[i] - 40) * 1.5;
           total += (wage * 40) + (ot * wage);
       }
       else
       {
           total += (wage * hs[i]);
       }
     }

     return total;
  }
```

Comment: hey thanks so much!

Comment: Just mark the answer as correct :)